# Create a pivot table with yearly index for each value

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm currently dealing with a worldbank dataset and I would like to pivot it to analyse it better.

Currently, it's in a form like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country Name' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],'Indicator' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z'],'2010' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'2011' : [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]}) 
print(df)



Country Name    Indicator   2010    2011
0   A               X         1       9
1   A               Y         2       8
2   A               Z         3       7
3   B               X         4       6
4   B               Y         5       5
5   B               Z         6       4
6   C               X         7       3
7   C               Y         8       2
8   C               Z         9       1
```

I simplified it, there's more columns with more yearly value but that's good enough to explain. Now I would like to get that table to pivot, so that I could get the indicators in columns, with the countries in index and the yearly values for the values. However for that I would like to have a df like this :

|  | year | indicator1 | indicator 2 | indicator3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | 2010 | values | . | . |
|  | 2011 | . | . | . |
| Country B | 2010 | . | . | . |
|  | 2011 | . | . | . |
| Country C | 2010 | . | . | . |

But since the values are stored in the year columns, I don't know how to transform it to get to this disposition

I tried doing it like this :

```
indicators = data.pivot_table(index='Country Name',columns='Indicator Name', values='2011', dropna=False)
```

This ofc works, but I just get the values for the year 2011 and I don't really want to create a dataframe for each year.

But I can't add the name of the year columns in the index as it creates an enormous dataframe for some reason, and if i just add them in the values it will only create more columns, with some kind of index on the columns to separate the years.

I don't know if there's a method to do what I'm looking for but I appreciate any help !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) before [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.melt(['Country Name', 'Indicator'], var_name='Year')
   .pivot_table(index=['Country Name', 'Year'],
                columns='Indicator', values='value')
)
```

Or reshape with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) (requires unique values, unlike `pivot_table`):

```
(df.set_index(['Country Name', 'Indicator'])
   .rename_axis(columns='Year').stack().unstack('Indicator')
)
```

output:

```
Indicator          X  Y  Z
Country Name Year         
A            2010  1  2  3
             2011  9  8  7
B            2010  4  5  6
             2011  6  5  4
C            2010  7  8  9
             2011  3  2  1
```